# An adequate topology?

Tags: general-topology

Given a topological space $(X,\tau)$. Define 
$f\in\bar{\mathscr C}\iff\forall x\in X: f(x)\in\overline{\{g(x)\in X|g\in\mathscr C\}}$, where $\mathscr C\subseteq End_\tau(X)$, the set of all continuous functions $X\to X$. Is this a closure operation on $End_\tau(X)$?

Comment: Can you please detail what do you mean by $End_\tau(X)$? Are you only talking about continuous functions $X\rightarrow X$? Please show us what you tried and your thoughts about this problem.

Comment: Do you intend some technical meaning for _adequate_? In any case what you describe is the topology of pointwise convergence.

Comment: @aes: is it? Consider $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$, with the discrete topology on $\{0,1\}$. Let $\mathscr C = \{g \mid g(x) = 0\text{ for precisely one } x\}$, and let $f$ be identically $0$. For the closure operator described in the question, we have $f\in\overline{\mathscr C}$. However, $f$ is not in the topological closure of $\mathscr C$, with the topology of pointwise convergence, as the open neighbourhood $\{h \in 2^\mathbb N \mid h(x) = 0\text{ for at least two x}\}$ does not contain any element of $\mathscr C$.

Comment: @zarathustra Indeed, thanks. In fact with $X = \{0,1\}$ this is not a topology. The closure of a single function would be the three functions agreeing with it at one point, but that implies the other function is open as a singleton, so the topology is discrete, a contradiction.

Comment: @Lehs: instead of putting the answer in your question, I suggest that you put that in the answer box below, and then accept the answer. The policy of this site encourages you to answer your own question, so that is not a problem, and this signals that this question received an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X=\{0,1\}$ the operator in the question is not a closure function.

> The closure of a single function would be the three functions agreeing
>   with it at one point, but that implies the other function is open as a
>   singleton, so the topology is discrete, a contradiction. (Comment by
>   aes).